# How to rewrite a javascript `replace` code to coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to use `basename` and `dirname` function in coffee script.
As a sample code I found javascript code from here.

http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/04/javascript-basename-and-dirname/

```
function basename(path) {
    return path.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\//, '' );
}

function dirname(path) {
    return path.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '');;
}
```

I tried to rewrite it, but it failed because of `"` and `'`.

```
basename = (path) -> path.replace(/\/g,'/').replace(/.*//, '')
dirname = (path) -> path.replace(/\/g,'/').replace(//[^/]*$/, '')
```

How can I write this code in coffee script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions aren't failing because of the quotes, it's because characters in your regular expressions aren't escaped properly.

```
basename = (path) -> path.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
dirname = (path) -> path.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')
```